# What is cost-sensitive regression?

Tags: regression, loss-functions

Is there such a thing as *cost-sensitive regression*? If so, where can I find information about it? For example, the regression assigns different costs/penalties to different features beforehand.

Comment: Are you quoting or referencing something?  What would it be?

Comment: How would this be different from weighted least squares?

Comment: @shane, WLS weights observations rather than variables, so I believe it is different from what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I missed that. Op: are you looking for an errors-in-variables method then?

Comment: The cost usually comes from missing the outcome variable ($y$), not the features, so what do you mean?